# "non-integer arg 1 for randrange()" in python libary

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

I use a randomizer to make random number from 5 to 10. Can't be so hard? I have used it previously on code (+2000 lines of code, too much for here) and no coding errors occurred.

My code is simply easter egg to my game but it broke all my code:

```
...
def slowp(t):       
    for l in t:
        sys.stdout.write(l)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        x=random.randint(0.1,0.9)
        time.sleep(x)
    print("")

if act=="++++++++++[>+++++++>++++++++++>+++>+<<<<-]>++.>+.+++++++..+++.>++.<<+++++++++++++++.>.+++.------.--------.>+.>":
    slowp("Hey, that is hello world made in brainfuck!")
...
```

`act` is a string whose value is provided by the user simply with `act=str(input("type here."))`. It is directly done before this part.

Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "startgame.py", line 2084, in <module>
    slowp("Hey, that is hello world made in brainfuck!")
  File "startgame.py", line 140, in slowp
    x=random.randint(0.1,0.9)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/random.py", line 216, in randint
    return self.randrange(a, b+1)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/random.py", line 180, in randrange
    raise ValueError("non-integer arg 1 for randrange()")
ValueError: non-integer arg 1 for randrange()
```

What is the actual problem?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are trying to pass *floating point* values to `random.randint()`. That function only takes *integers*.

You need to use the [`random.uniform()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.uniform) instead; it'll produce a uniformly random value between the lower and upper bound (inclusive):

> Return a random floating point number N such that a <= N <= b for a <= b and b <= N <= a for b < a.

Demo:

```
>>> import random
>>> random.uniform(0.1, 0.9)
0.6793304134926453
```

Comment: Or if the intention is to pass and generate integers, cast params to `int()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
ValueError: non-integer arg 1 for randrange()
```

`random.randint(0.1,0.9)`

You have to pass integers to that function. 0.1 and 0.9 are not integers

Answer (score 0):

you can

```
random.randint(1,9)/10
```

in random.randint(start, stop, step) we can use step

random.uniform(start, stop) - no step